# SSO (single sign On) using Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, single-sign-on

Is this feasible?
1. User login to their office desktop (window OS) with LDAP authentication
2. Open a browser to my application, eg. http:///webappsABC
3. My application authenticate using LAN ID/ldap login id vs LDAP server.
4. Auto login to my application. (without user key in the username/password)

Any sample code or URL for this settings will much appreciated.

Thanks